# Daniel and King Cyrus

Tags: daniel

Did King Cyrus know about what God had anointed him to do? If so, who told King Cyrus about what God had determined the king would do?

Answer (score 3):

**Daniel and King Cyrus**

Check out the following for who did the telling:-

> **Isaiah, Chap 45, [NASB]** *1. Thus says the Lord to Cyrus His anointed, Whom I have taken by the right hand, To subdue nations before him, And to loose the loins of kings; To open doors before him so that gates will not be shut: 2. "I will go before you and make the rough places smooth; I will shatter the doors of bronze, and cut through their iron bars. 3. And I will give you the treasures of darkness, And hidden wealth of secret places, In order that you may know that it is I, The Lord the God of Israel, who calls you by your name."*

...and so on and so on. Daniel himself, being there in Babylon at it's overthrow by the Medes and Persians, led by **Cyrus the Great** and being of great importance to Darius the Mede and Cyrus the Persian, would also have no doubt imparted the news of Cyrus' anointing.

Comment: +1 nice answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Isaiah 45:

> 1This is what the LORD says to **Cyrus** His anointed,
> whose right hand I have grasped
> to subdue nations before him,
> to disarm kings,
> to open the doors before him,
> so that the gates will not be shut

God himself might have spoken to Cyrus.

2 Ch 36:

> 22
> In the first year of Cyrus king of Persia, in order to fulfill the word of the LORD spoken by Jeremiah, **the LORD moved the heart of Cyrus** king of Persia to make a proclamation throughout his realm and also to put it in writing:

Daniel could have told Cyrus, Dan 10:

> 1 In the third year of **Cyrus** king of Persia, a revelation was given to **Daniel**

who told King Cyrus about what God had determined the king would do?

God could have told him directly. He could have heard it from Daniel, or through someone who knew about Isaiah's writing.

Comment: Yes, Cyrus could have been aware of Isaiah's writings and heard from Daniel firsthand, but could not have heard from Ezra in any shape or form.

Comment: Right. I deleted the offending lines. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, now I can upvote and thank you for recognizing my answer.

Comment: I am unsure of your first sentence - Isaiah lived over 100 years before Cyrus, so Isaiah could not have informed Cyrus himself.

Comment: Right. I deleted the offending words. Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you for the answers to my question. I appreciate it.